# HTTP 404 Servlet

Tags: servlets, file-upload, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to send a file with Servlet **3.0**/JSP (IDE : Eclipse)

Here my JSP code :

```
<form method="post" action="UploadServlet"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="file" size="60" /><br />
    <br /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

And my Servlet :

```
@WebServlet
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 2,
maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10,
maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50)
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final String SAVE_DIR = "uploadFiles";

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{


    //CODE

}
```

But when i submit my form, i got an error HTTP 404 The requested resource is not available.

Why ?

Comment: Where is the path for your servlet defined? Did you try `@WebServlet("/UploadServlet")`?

Comment: Yes I tried and ot doesn't work. When i submit a normal form like <form action="Sauvegarde" method="post"> it works on the servlet : @WebServlet("/Sauvegarde")
public class Sauvegarde extends HttpServlet

Comment: To simplify : I have two classes
@WebServlet("/UploadServlet")
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet
and

@WebServlet("/Sauvegarde")
public class Sauvegarde extends HttpServlet

    <form action="UploadServlet" method="post" >
        <br /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>

doesnt work but

    <form action="Sauvegarde" method="post" >
        <br /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>

works

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify urlPatterns  like

```
@WebServlet(name = "name", urlPatterns = {"/pattern"})
```

[see here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/javaee6/helloWorldExample.shtml)  for example

Comment: I already tried with @WebServlet("/UploadServlet") and it doesnt work.

Comment: I precize that I got another form : <form action="Sauvegarde" method="post"> and it works fine !

Comment: With : @WebServlet(name = "name", urlPatterns = {"/upload"}) and <form method="post" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data"> it doesn't work